# Lambda of Fluent API?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, fluent

Tried to replace lambdas with anonymous class in Stream API (below code) and it works fine. I want to understand how the parameter required for the test(T t) method is getting generated from.

Lambda

```
                list.stream()
                .map(String::length)
                .filter(t->t>4).count();
```

Anonymous class

```
                list.stream()//line1
                .map(String::length)
                .filter(new Predicate<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(Integer t) {//line 5
                        
                        return t>4;
                    }
                }).count();
```

While using lambdas we pass the parameter using the lambda notation, but I dont understand how the `Integer t` at line 5 is getting generated from. Is it due to the `Fluent API` in `Stream` or due to the functional interface(lambda)?

Edit : I am clear about `lambda` version, dont understand how the version with `anonymous class` is working? To put in another way, would it work in `Java 1.7` (provided we wrote something similar to `Stream API`, we just wont have lambdas).

Edit : For anyone confused like I was, please look at https://github.com/fmcarvalho/quiny , simplified implementation of Stream API by some smart guy

Comment: Yes, it would have worked in Java 7 with anonymous classes.  (Some third-party libraries did exactly that, e.g. Guava's FluentIterable.)

Comment: OK Thanks. So its the Fluent API thats responsible for this functionality?

Comment: I mean, it's not really the "fluent API" that's responsible.  It's just...how those language features work.

Comment: Ok, which feature in java, Method chaining? But I dont see this keyword being used here, which is used usualy in method chaining.

Comment: Method chaining isn't actually a language feature, it's just a way of using the language.  It's not actually related to the use of the `Predicate` at all.  The use of `this` isn't necessary to achieve method chaining, either.

Comment: I understand method chaining is just a way of de-referencing. Could you please explain what feature is causing, if not Fluent API?

Comment: ...causing _what_?  There isn't anything going on here more significant than anonymous inner classes or lambdas implementing an interface.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `t -> t > 4`, Java automatically infers the type of this lambda -- it must be a `Predicate<Integer>`, given that it's being passed to `filter` on a `Stream<Integer>` -- and then automatically figures out that it must be `(Integer t) -> t > 4`.